# Android Studio can't see the design

Tags: android

Does anyone knows why I get this View ? I added a button and changed the background color but can't see it.

[image]

Comment: Try to change the api version or refreshing the view.

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali i tried it already .but nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried file-> Invalidate cache or build -> CleanProject

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
Refresh,
Change from android N to another version,
Clean Project,
Rebuild Project,
Restart Android Studio.
If those don't work there might be an issue with your xml. If that's the case, then try changing the root view of activity_main to a relativelayout and setting the context explicitly:

```
<RelativeLayout
...
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context= "com.company.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
...>...</>
```

Answer (score -1):

**[Solution 1]** go to menu bar Click on > Build > Clean Project  & Build Project

**[Solution 2**] go to menu bar Click on > Synchronize Button up left  next the save button   or  tap (CTRL+ALT+y)

**[Solution 3]** try to update the API    & see if  Android studio has updates

**[Solution 4]** go to SDK Manger  and install package which the Android studio need   it will be shown   if not   \ Install   API 16  or  18

**[Solution 5]** uninstall Android studio  and install it again